# Criteria query - setFetchMode vs createAlias, n+1 selects

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, criteria-api

I have a bidirectional one-to-one association between Car and Engine mapped as follows: (with Hibernate 3.6)

```
<class name="org.example.Car">
    <id column="id" name="PID">
        <generator class="uuid2" />
    </id>
    <version name="Version" column="version" />

    <many-to-one cascade="all" name="Engine" not-null="true" unique="true" />
</class>
<class name="org.example.Engine">
    <id column="id" name="PID">
        <generator class="uuid2" />
    </id>
    <version name="Version" column="version" />

    <one-to-one cascade="all" name="Car" property-ref="Engine" />
</class>
```

When I perform the following criteria query to load all Cars and eager fetch their Engines

```
session().createCriteria(Car.class)
   .setFetchMode("Engine", FetchMode.JOIN)
   .list();
```

I get one select to find all Cars, and then another select for each Car that was found:

```
select this_.id  ... from Car this_ inner join Engine engine2_ on this_.Engine=engine2_.id
select car0_.id  ... from Car car0_ where car0_.engine=?
select car0_.id  ... from Car car0_ where car0_.engine=?
select car0_.id  ... from Car car0_ where car0_.engine=?
...
```

It appears that Hibernate gets confused when setting the properties on each `Engine` that was loaded. In `TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity`, it attempts to resolve the Car property on `Engine` and issues another select.

If use createAlias instead of setFetchMode, I get the expected single select and everything works:

```
session().createCriteria(Car.class)
   .createAlias("Engine", "engine")
   .list();
```

I was under the impression that those two criteria queries should behave the same. Is there something I can change in my mapping? Should I start using createAlias instead of setFetchMode?

**UPDATE:** So, the second query isn't good either. It actually joins Engine and then joins Car again for the back-reference:

```
select this._id  ... from Car this_
   inner join Engine engine1_ on this_.engine=engine1_.id
   left outer join Car car3_ on engine1_.id=car3_.engine
```

It doesn't seem like hibernate realizes they are 2 ends of the same association. Removing the reference from Engine -> Car fixes it but it would be nice if I could get this to work while keeping the reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is related to the bug in hibernate. You can check if the workaround posted there works for you.

[Bug Report](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-3524)